# How can I horizontally centre a specific letter of a word?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't figure out how to centre a specific letter of a word inside a div (rather than the whole word). I've illustrated the problem using images below, where I want to center the letter N of the word Ipnos:

[current outcome with flexbox which centres the whole word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5Xfy.png)
[desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBE5m.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Please add the relevant code to your question _ Take a moment to visit SO Help Center and specifically the section on 'Asking' >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach to achieve the effect you're looking for.

The light-gray `x-axis` and the `y-axis` are there only to demonstrate that at all times, the **N** remains in the center of the container.

The second version of the container gives the flex-spaced `<spans>` a red outline to show more clearly how the CSS enables the **N** to always remain central.

**Working Example:**

```js
const myDivs = [... document.getElementsByTagName('div')];
let divTextArray;
let divContent;

myDivs.forEach((div) => {

  divTextArray = [... div.textContent];
  divContent = '';
  
  divTextArray.forEach((letter) => {
    divContent += '<span>' + letter + '</span>';
  });
  
  div.innerHTML = divContent;
  div.innerHTML += '<div class="x-axis"></div>';
  div.innerHTML += '<div class="y-axis"></div>';
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 12px;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
}

.container span {
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) span {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.x-axis,
.y-axis {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);
}

.x-axis {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
}

.y-axis {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Resize the containers below...</h2>
<div class="container">Ipnos</div>
<div class="container">Ipnos</div>
```

---

## Explanation:

Using a combination of:

- surrounding each letter with a `<span>` (using javascript)
- declaring a width of `20%` for each `span` (ie. one fifth, because there are 5 letters)
- CSS `flexbox` to ensure that all the `<spans>` are positioned relative to the horizontal and vertical center of their `<div class="container">`
- declaring `text-align: center` for each `<span>` to ensure that each letter is positioned exactly in the center of its parent `<span>`

you can ensure that the center of the centermost letter of the five corresponds with the horizontal center of `<div class="container">`.

Comment: Hi Rounin! This seems like a great way to achieve what I was looking for! 
Before I accept the answer, I'm having some difficulty understanding how it's been achieved. Could you briefly explain your methodology?

Comment: Sure. See my explanation above. Do please follow up with specific questions if you are uncertain about anything.

Comment: Thanks! I've accepted your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the `transform:translate();` property on the word itself. You could position it with the method you are using right now and slightly adjust the word's position.
I used this on the container of the word to center the word both vertically and horizontally:

```
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
```

And then I used this style on the word itself to slightly shift it to the right

```
  transform: translate(5%);
```

See the codepen below. The top word is just centered, the second word is centered but shifted to the right.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/nazar-klymenko/pen/dyyMVGN